# Using a remote domain as an secondary address to a single mailbox on Exchange

Tags: exchange, mailbox, domain

We have two Exchange mail servers. Athens and Paris. Each one resides on a different subnet in a different location.

Paris is handling one domain: cat.com
Athens is handling many domains, including dog.com

Is it possible for user Joe@cat.com, whose mailbox is obviously residing in Paris, to switch his mail address to Joe@dog.com, while keeping his Joe@cat.com address too? The "reply" address should be Joe@dog.com though.

I am thinking about migrating his mailbox from Paris to Athens, giving him the Joe@dog.com address in the process. Then creating a "remote email" (I cannot remember the proper term) in Paris for joe@dog.com, and a distribution group which will be sending emails from Joe@cat.com to Joe@dog.com.

Is there a better way to do this?

(Note: Paris is using Exchange 2003 and Athens is using Exchange 2010)

Comment: are they in the same AD Forest?

Answer (score 0):

You could go as you planned and create a mailbox for him in Paris and update this mailbox in Athens. In Athens you would create a mail-enabled contact for him with his new Paris (@dog.com) email, and in Exchange change the delivery restrictions to forward mail to that mail-enabled contact. Then instead of filling his inbox in Athens (which he no longer monitors) you forward mail to his new Paris (@dog.com) mailbox. No distribution list needed. He get all mail in the same inbox but be advised he will not be able to send as joe@cat.com anymore, only joe@dog.com.

Comment: It all depends if they are in the forest. If they are, he can just add another e-mail address to the account in Paris, and make the new address the default.

Comment: Right Michael, I did not get the feeling that they were from reading his question, but if they are then no need to mess with mail contacts at all.

Comment: I think you mixed "Paris" with "Athens" in your answer but I get the point. the end result would be to have two mailboxes for that user and simply forwarding mail to his new mailbox (@dog.com). I am trying to avoid using CALs so I guess this will not be optimal for me so I guess I'll go with the migration from Paris to Athens and then remove the user from Paris altogether. Oh and there's no forest as you guessed. Thank you.